# How to inject two instances of same object using Autofac?

Tags: autofac, constructor-injection

I'm using Autofac constructor injection.  I need to figure out how to inject a single object instance into more than one constructor argument, without needing to explicitly resolve each argument during the container setup phase.

I have a complex scenario which would be simplified by this behavior; the following example is just a simplified scenario so I can demonstrate the behavior I'm looking for.

**Example:**

**Say I have these two interfaces, IOpenable and ICloseable:**

```cs
public interface IOpenable
{
    void Open();
}
public interface ICloseable
{
    void Close();
}
```

**And I have this Door class which implements both of them:**

```cs
public interface IDoor : IOpenable, ICloseable { }
public class Door : IDoor, IOpenable, ICloseable 
{
    void Open() { ... }
    void Close() { ... }
}
```

**And I have this class which accepts an IOpenable and an ICloseable:**

```cs
public class DoorHandler : IDoorHandler
{
    public DoorHandler(IOpenable openable, ICloseable closeable)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**Question:**

Is it possible to tell autofac to inject the *same* Door object into both arguments whenever both an IOpenable and ICloseable are dependencies in the same constructor?

**Note: I can't do**:

```cs
container.Register<IDoorHandler>( c => {
    Door d = c.Resolve<IDoor>();
    return new DoorHandler(d,d)
});
```

That *would* do what I want, but remember that this DoorHandler class is just an example.  In my real code, the "DoorHandler" is really an MVC Controller and I'm registering it with RegisterControllers().  So I can't register it like the above.  Besides, sometimes dependency graphs can get overly complex and doing this explicitly in every case can become overwhelming.

I guess what I'm looking for is to be able to do something like:

```cs
container.RegisterType<DoorHandler>().As<IDoorHandler>();
container.RegisterType<Door>().As<IDoor>();
container.Register<IOpenable>( c => c.ResolveShared<IDoor>(); );
container.Register<ICloseable>( c => c.ResolveShared<IDoor>(); );
```

where calls to `c.ResolveShared<T>` will all resolve to the same T object if called for more than one argument in same constructor.

Or perhaps:

```cs
container.RegisterType<DoorHandler>().As<IDoorHandler>();
container.RegisterType<Door>().As<IDoor>().InstancePerDependencyShared();
container.Register<IOpenable>( c => c.Resolve<IDoor>(); );
container.Register<ICloseable>( c => c.Resolve<IDoor>(); );
```

Obviously if I was using an InstancePerLifetimeScope or something for the Door object, each resolved Door would be the same instance. But I don't want that, I want a new instance of Door each time a DoorHandler is created, and I want that Door to be passed as both arguments to the DoorHandler constructor.

Comment: Autofac OOB as you say, doesn't support this. But your `DoorHandle` sample doesn't illustrate *why* you need to have the one class be resolved like this. Had I implemented `DoorHandle` I would have it take an `IDoor` and be done with it :) Perhaps if you described your real problem, we could better understand and perhaps see other ways of structuring your object model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok tricky one :) ... Here's one possible solution for generalised "per constructor" sharing:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(asm)        
    .OnPreparing(e => {
        var spr = new SharedConstructorParameter(
            typeof(IOpenable),
            typeof(ICloseable));
        e.Parameters = new Parameter[]{ spr }.Concat(e.Parameters);
    });
```

The parameter needs to be set up in the `OnPreparing()` event because the `SharedConstructorParameter` instance will be the cache of values per resolve operation.

```
class SharedConstructorParameter : Parameter
{
    object _cachedInstance;
    Type[] _sharedParameterTypes;

    public SharedConstructorParameter(params Type[] sharedParameterTypes)
    {
        _sharedParameterTypes = sharedParameterTypes;
    }

    protected override bool CanSupplyValue(
        ParameterInfo pi,
        IComponentContext cc,
        out Func<object> valueCreator)
    {
        valueCreator = null;
        if (!_sharedParameterTypes.Contains(pi.ParameterType))
            return false;

         valueCreator = () => {
             _cachedInstance = _cachedInstance ?? cc.Resolve(pi.ParameterType);
             return cachedInstance;
         };
         return true;
    }
}
```

Yours to compile and debug ;)

Comment: Thanks man, looks promising. I'll test it out sometime later.

Comment: Interesting solution. Looks good. Only drawback will be that you'll need to know up front the set of all of the param types you want to share in constructors. Not a huge restriction, but not as "automated" as the simplicity of lifetime scope. Pros and cons, pros and cons. :)

Answer (score 2):

The closest you'll get with Autofac as it stands today is to register things as InstancePerLifetimeScope. However, that may be enough if the specific use case you have is an MVC controller.

With Autofac's ASP.NET integration, every incoming HTTP request has its own lifetime scope, so if you have this...

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly);
// Under the covers, this is really doing...
// builder.RegisterType<DoorController>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

That InstancePerHttpRequest is an extension similar to InstancePerLifetimeScope. A new lifetime scope is created around your HTTP request and disposed at the end.

Then you can register your shared-lifetime-objects also as InstancePerHttpRequest:

```
builder.RegisterType<Door>().As<IDoor>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.RegisterType<Openable>().As<IOpenable>();
builder.RegisterType<Closeable>().As<ICloseable>();
var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

And now when your controller is resolved, the IDoor will be the same instance in both the IOpenable and ICloseable instances.

If you are outside of a request scope, the best you can do is something like:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<DoorHandler>().As<IDoorHandler>();
builder.RegisterType<Door>().As<IDoor>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<Openable>().As<IOpenable>();
builder.RegisterType<Closeable>().As<ICloseable>();
var container = builder.Build();
```

Register the "shared" items as InstancePerLifetimeScope. Then when you need to resolve, you can do something like:

```
using(var lifetime = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
  var dh = lifetime.Resolve<IDoorHandler>();
  // The IDoor will be the same in both references here.
}
```

You could technically put the reference to the door handler outside the using statement, but then if your IDoor implementations are disposable, they'll get disposed along with the lifetime scope at the end of the using, so be careful with that.

Comment: Sensible suggestions - never say never though ;) I took on the challenge below, think it might work, needs another set of eyes on it...