# Autofac: Create named scope on resolving

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

Is it possible in Autofac to auto-instantiate types each time another certain type is resolved and to create a named scope for the certain type?

E.g.

```
builder.Register<MyType>.As<IMyType>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterAsAutoInstantiateType<IMyType, MySubType>().As<IMySubType>();

class MySubType(IMyType myType)
{
    ...
}
```

I already tried it with Owned, with OnActivated and the resolve an `IEnumerable<IMySubType>` each time the `IMyType` is resolved but what I want is to create a new lifetime scope for each `IMyType` and the auto resolve and instantiate all types registered for that  `IMyType` scope.

Comment: This is a fairly uncommon thing to want to do (like, I've never heard of a requirement like this in my years of working with Autofac) so I'm curious if maybe there's a different way to solve the problem you're looking at. That is, you've specified a solution involving complex creation of lifetime scopes and things... but what's the challenge that's addressing? Perhaps there's a different way to handle it that doesn't involve this level of complexity.

Comment: @Travis-Illig I try to formulate it in one sentence: The caller creates objects of type A (resp. resolves a Func<IA>() to create As) and plugins should provide types that are automatically instantiated when As are created and it should be kind of generic so that plugins cannot only specify types that are created when As are created but also for other types.

Comment: It would be good to expand on that by updating your question. Sounds like there's some sort of plugin mechanism... There are "types that are automatically instantiated" but what holds references to them? The get created and instantly lose scope? What does a plugin look like? (This should all go in the question, not in comments...)

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working as per your requirement. Only tactic is that your type will get instantiated twice. To overcome this, I've made two registration. Kindly have a look and let us know.

```
        //Lighweight registration
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<TestItem>().As<ITestItem>();


        //Actual regirstation
        containerBuilder.Register((c, qe) =>
        {
            var subType = c.Resolve<IsubType>();
            return new TestItem(subType);

        }).As<ITestItem>().Keyed("TestKey", typeof(ITestItem));


        containerBuilder.RegisterBuildCallback(builtContainer =>
        {
            //Filter for types
            foreach (var registration in builtContainer.ComponentRegistry.Registrations)
            {
                registration.Activating += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                 {
                     var instanseLookup = eventArgs.Context as IInstanceLookup;
                     if (instanseLookup != null && !instanseLookup.ActivationScope.Tag.Equals("Manual"))
                     {
                         var scope = builtContainer.BeginLifetimeScope("Manual");
                         eventArgs.Instance = scope.ResolveKeyed<ITestItem>("TestKey");
                     }


                 };
            }
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not, because I not only want to have one item but multiple ones. It is like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710900/autofac-scope-around-a-resolved-instance but with the additional requirement that A does not has a relation to B and C but B and C have a relation to A and should be automatically created when A is created.

Comment: @TheWizard Do you want B and C to be resolved from the scope created for A?

Comment: Exactly. When A is created A should have its own scope within that B and C should be create immediately after (or within?) the resolve operation of A. Should be in the way like you have an object in the root scope e.g. Z that does: `public Z(Func<A> create) {... _myListofAs.Add(create()) ... }`. Autofac should then automatically dispose the As that are not needed anymore (e.g. when removed from the list) and within that clean up the B and C for that lifetime scope

Comment: @TheWizard In above code, when some component asks for instanse of ITestItem,TestItem is created using "containerBuilder.RegisterType<TestItem>().As<ITestItem>();" and `Activating` event occurs. In this event we create instance of `TestItem` again using keyed registration from a new scope. If all `B` and `C` are used as parameter constructor you can initialize them in keyed registration. I see the above code is fulfilling your requirement. Only issue is that it creating instance two time for a single call.